# How can I align linear and ordinal scales in d3 graphs?

Tags: d3.js, scala.js

I have an ordinal scale, that I am creating a bar chart with.
I create it like this:

```
d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands(js.Tuple2(0, widthOfMySvgElem), 0.1)
    .domain(labels)
```

The labels are in fact weeks, or months, or similiar periods, and I have data for those periods.

Now, I have something like expected values, that I want to show in this graph as well.
Furthermore, those expected values can change in time, and I want to display that too.

I want to display, that I have `expectedValue1` in march, and the start of April, but then at 7th of April, the expected value changed to `expectedValue2`, and I want to place it where the 7th of April would be on my axis. (I want to display those expected values as the straight line, that changes height as value change.)

But I have no luck matching exact location in relation to this ordinal axis.
Do you have any ideas how can I successfully align those two scales, so they will meet at the data points of ordinal scale, but that I would be able to position other values correctly as well?

Comment: I stopped reading your question here: *"I have an ordinal scale, that I am creating a line chart with"*. Can you explain why (and how) are you using an ordinal scale for a line chart?

Comment: I have a graph that can be either a bar chart or line chart (depending on some flag). So in the bar chart, I am creating bars for values, in the line chart, I am connecting dots.
I have changed the line you are referencing.